# AngularJS Unknown Providor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: poductResource is not defined
angular.js:12416 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productResourceProvider <- productResource <- ProductListCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=productResourceProvider%20%3C-%20productResource%20%3C-%20ProductListCtrl

Here is my view:

```
<head>
<title>Acme Product Management</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="common/services/common.services.js"></script>
<script src="common/services/productResource.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="common/services/productResourceMock.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="productManagement">
<div class="panel panel-primary"></div>
<div class="panel-heading" style="font-size:large">
    Product List
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table" ng-controller="ProductListCtrl as vm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.toggleImage()">{{vm.showImage ? "Hide" : "Show" }} Image</button></td>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
                <td><img ng-if="vm.showImage" ng-src="{{product.imageUrl}}" style="width:50px; margin:2px" title="{{product.productName}}" /></td>
                <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                <td>{{product.productCode}}</td>
                <td>{{product.releaseDate}}</td>
                <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
.module("productManagement")
.controller("ProductListCtrl", ['productResource', ProductListCtrl]);

function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
    var vm = this;

    productResource.query(function (data) {
        vm.products = data;
    });

    vm.showImage = false;
    vm.toggleImage = function () {
        vm.showImage = !vm.showImage;
    }
}
}());
```

This is my common service:

```
    (function () {
"use strict";
angular
.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]);
}());
```

And here is my ProductResource service:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
.module("common.services")
.factory("productResource", ['$resource', productResource]);

function productResource($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/products/:productId")
}
}());
```

Here is my productResourceMock module.

```
    (function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("productResourceMock", ["ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function ($httpBackend) {
    var products = [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "productName": "Leaf Rake",
            "productCode": "GDN-0011",
            "releaseDate": "March 19, 2009",
            "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch handle.",
            "cost": 9.00,
            "price": 19.95,
            "category": "garden",
            "tags": ["leaf", "tool"],
            "imageUrl": "that.jpg"
        },
        {
           "productId": 5,
           "productName": "Hammer",
           "productCode": "TBX-0048",
           "releaseDate": "May 21,2013",
           "description": "Curved claw steel hammer",
           "cost": 1.00,
           "price": 8.99,
           "category": "toolbox",
           "tags": ["tool"],
           "imageUrl": "this.jpg"

       }

    ];

    var productUrl = "/api/products"

    $httpBackend.whenGET(productUrl).respond(products);

})

}());
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have a typo I believe. Change all of the instances of poduct to product.

Comment: I did change the typo.  I'm still getting error message.

Comment: Can you edit the original post so the first bit of code shows as code with the rest? I think you just need to indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Correct dependency annotation should be:

```
.factory("productResource", ['$resource', productResource]);
```

Note, that `'$resource'` is a **string**. You was passing some `$resource` undeclared *variable*, hence the first pure javascript `ReferenceError`. The second one if the one thrown by Angular because you never provided dependency information.

Comment: @dfsq I changed it as you requested and fixed the syntax error, I'll update my question in a sec.  I'm still getting the error message?

Comment: @hollyquinn What message are you getting? Also make sure it's `productResource` not `poductResource `.

Comment: I did correct the spelling mistake.  The error message I'm getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: poductResource is not defined
angular.js:12416 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productResourceProvider <- productResource <- ProductListCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=productResourceProvider%20%3C-%20productResource%20%3C-%20ProductListCtrl

Comment: How come you get `Uncaught ReferenceError: poductResource` if you fixed spelling?

Comment: oh it's fixed.  Thank you so much.  I had to reload the page.  Sorry about that.  You are a lifestyle.  I'll have to watch for those typos.  ;)  Thanks.